# IOS: Cannot get correct screen size

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, screen-size, skspritenode, sknode

I tried to display some `SKNodes` and I used the width and height of screen to set their positions in order to make them compatible with different screen sizes.

```
SKNode* obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:obstacleSize];
obstacle.position = CGPointMake(80, self.size.height * 0.38);
obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:obstacle.frame.size];
```

But nodes' positions still change when I run the program with a different screen size (fine in 3.5 inch but wrong in 4-inch). And I found that `self.size.height` is not the actual height of the screen.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: don't present scene in viewDidLoad, move it to viewWillLayoutSubviews to get correct size. Look around to find the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

`[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size` returns a CGSize with the width and height of the screen. See the [UIScreen Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds).

Comment: What results are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

`[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size` should return the correct `CGSize` vector of the width and height. However, if you are in landscape, the values will be reversed, then what'd you would expect from portrait.